# sed: Nested pattern replacement

Tags: regex, sed, nested

I have a bunch of C code, that involves calls of a power function of the form:

`Power(x,2)`

I want to expand it, so that all powers are written out explicitly, so for example `Power(x,2)` should be replaced with `(x)*(x)`.
I am currently using the following `sed` command:

`sed -e 's/Power(\([^,]*\),2)/(\1)*(\1)/g' main.c`

This works fine for simple cases such as `Power(x,2)` or `Power(x+y-3*z,2)`.
However, as soon as I have nested calls of the function, it no longer works. I want it to start with the innermost instance of the function and work outwards. For instance, if the input is

`Power(Power(x,2) + x,2)`

The expected output would be

`((x)*(x) + x)*((x)*(x) + x)`

But using the expression above, it returns

`(Power(x)*(Power(x) + x,2)`

Is there a simple and elegant way to fix this?

Comment: There's a way in `sed`, provided you don't use `Power` for powers other than 2. (sed is not good with numbers.) I don't know that I'd call it simple.

Comment: Would you mind telling me the way? If it is not simple it's not too bad, as long as it works.

Comment: I think this could be solved by telling sed to start from the right end of the input and work its way to the left. This way it would first hit the innermost Power() and unwrap it and only then hit the outer one. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),2\)/($1)*($1)/){}'` works for your given samples, but I think won't work for all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on given samples:

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
Power(Power(x,2) + x,2)
Power(x+y-3*z,2)
Power(x + Power(x,2),2)

$ perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),2\)/($1)*($1)/){}' ip.txt
((x)*(x) + x)*((x)*(x) + x)
(x+y-3*z)*(x+y-3*z)
(x + (x)*(x))*(x + (x)*(x))
```

- `while` loop will work as long the substitution succeeds
- `(?:(?!Power\().)+?` this will minimally match text after `Power(` as long as it isn't `Power(`

  - non-greedy quantifier is needed to stop at the first occurrence of `,2`
  - `(?:(?!REGEXP).)+` is a general way to match text as long as the given REGEXP doesn't match, similar to `[^set]+` which matches *characters* other than the given set.

For generic powers (instead of specific case of `2`):

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
Power(Power(x,2),3)
Power(Power(x,3),2)

$ perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),(\d+)\)/"($1)" . "*($1)" x ($2-1)/e){}' ip.txt
((x)*(x))*((x)*(x))*((x)*(x))
((x)*(x)*(x))*((x)*(x)*(x))
```

- `(\d+)` capture the power value
- `"($1)" . "*($1)" x ($2-1)` build the expanded version using string concatenation operator `.` and string repetition operator `x` and the captured power value
- `e` flag to allow Perl code in replacement section

Comment: Hello Sundeep, I hope you still read this.
While this solution works well for the problems I mentioned in the original post, it fails when I have nested powers with different arguments.
To be more specific, I have an expression like
Power(Power(x,2),3)
 I first use the command
`perl -pe while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),2\)/($1)*($1)/){}' file.txt`
and then
`perl -pe while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),3\)/($1)*($1)*($1)/){}' file.txt`
which works fine. But when the order of Powers is exchanged, i.e.
Power(Power(x,3),2)
the output is wrong:
Power((x,3))*(x,3))
Do you know a fix?

Comment: How about `perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),(\d+)\)/"($1)" . "*($1)" x ($2-1)/e){}'`